# Ember Difference between Restadapter vs Jsonapiadapter

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

Ember uses Restadapter & Jsonapiadapter for the adapters.
What are the exact differences between the 2 in terms of data formats for request/response ?
Any other things we need to ensure when using any of these 2.

Answer (score 4):

The [JSONAPIAdapter](https://emberjs.com/api/ember-data/release/classes/DS.JSONAPIAdapter) conforms to the [JSONApi](http://jsonapi.org/) spec

Use [RESTAdapter](https://emberjs.com/api/ember-data/release/classes/DS.RESTAdapter)  when you have an JSON API that follows a REST endpoint with pluralized object names and has a root node using the name of the object being returned.

Examples below:

Example JSONAPI spec object:

```
{
  "data": [{
    "type": "articles",
    "id": "1",
    "attributes": {
      "title": "JSON API paints my bikeshed!"
    },
    "relationships": {
      "author": {
        "links": {
          "self": "http://example.com/articles/1/relationships/author",
          "related": "http://example.com/articles/1/author"
        },
        "data": { "type": "people", "id": "7" }
      }
    },
  }],
  "included": [{
    "type": "people",
    "id": "7",
    "attributes": {
      "name": "Dave",
      "twitter": "kiwiupover"
    }
  }]
}
```

Example Rest json api object:

```
{
  "posts": {
    "id": 5,
    "title": "An API that gets bikeshed for months ",
    "author": "kiwiupover",
    "comments": [1]
  },
  "comments": [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Dave",
  }]
}
```

Ember Data provides straightforward methods for adapting your DS.adapter to your specific JSON API shape.

There is a third [adapter](https://emberjs.com/api/ember-data/release/classes/DS.Adapter) from which the previously mentioned adapters are extended from.

Comment: Thanks a lot...Are the differences only in terms of data types (request/response)...Any difference when defining the Model class itself. Also any other difference in the app code that we should take care (in routes/controller classes, etc)

Comment: Also just a question regarding data formats...It seems the 2 adapters REST/JSON require us to follow conventions regarding the data format itself..Is there any other adapter I can use which is very flexible meaning it would accept any valid JSON format...I do not have much flexibility with changing the server-side response...So was just wondering...

Comment: The difference between the adapters is more about the expected endpoints isn't it? Payload serialization and deserialization (also called normalization in Ember Data) is responsibility of the Serializer isn't it?

Comment: @jelhan it is but the OP seems unable to go through basic documentation and prefers to use stackoverflow as their search engine

Comment: @PatsyIssa You're both arrogant and wrong, which is to be expected from a comment on SO. EmeberJS docs on serializers and adapters are obtuse. RestAdapter's docs actually include RestSerializer's part, so the OP's confusion is perfectly understandable. What OP probably needs is RestAdapter and JsonSerializer.